# Eclipse shows that it builds, but doesn't

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse is acting really weird. When I do a build/clean and build, it doesn't throw any errors, but in fact it doesn't really do a new build. Only if I restart and do a build, does it do an actual build. Would anyone know what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the option "Build automatically" selected in the preferences?

[image]

(From Lars Vogel's [Cleaning up the workspace (without re-building)](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/08/17/cleaning-workspace-without-re-building/) )

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse's project-> Build working set->make sure all your working sets are selected
Then go to project->select Build Automatic option